# C++ - Insertion Operator, const Keyword Causes Compiler Error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

So I'm building a class, for simplicity, I'll dumb it down here.

This gives a compiler error: "Error: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function."

This is the code:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Foo& f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++)
        out << f.at(i) << ", ";

    out << endl;
    return out;
}
```

the at(int i) functions returns a value from an array at index i.

If I remove the const keyword from Foo, everything works great. Why?

EDIT: Per request, the declarations for the member functions.

.h

```
public:
    int size(void);
    int at(int);
```

.cpp

```
  int Foo::size()
    {
       return _size; //_size is a private int to keep track size of an array.
    }

    int Foo::at(int i)
    {
       return data[i]; //where data is an array, in this case of ints
    }
```

Comment: How are `Foo::at` and `Foo::size` declared?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare your "at" function and your "size" function as const, otherwise they cannot act on const objects.

So, your function might look something like this:

```
int Foo::at(int i)
{
     // whatever
}
```

And it needs to look like this:

```
int Foo::at(int i) const
{
     // whatever
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to find information on this since you brought it to my attention, but I'm finding my searches somewhat inefficient (Generally wading through all the other uses of the keyword const), by chance do you have a reference on it?

Comment: @DivinusVox: Sure, [here ya go.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10)

Comment: If you want to Google it for more information, try [const member function c++](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=const+member+function+c%2B%2B&cp=22&qe=Y29uc3QgbWVtYmVyIGZ1bmN0aW9uIA&qesig=DqNoS265PW-OV1W4fJKLTg&pkc=AFgZ2tlZ1z5HD9rGViIHpFuc_SD02K1_M9TSs4bGzk6RAa3dMm_gG8DcwAB6cdwkmm0HD6JkOkwM_7E7ZWv-wZ3eI5MmL_vDow&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=const+member+function+&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e9ce1e11ecd3b0b1)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a function which changes the object on a constant object. You have to make sure that the function `at` doesn't change the object of class `Foo` by declaring it as `const` (or remove the `const` in the parameter to allow `at` do whatever it does if it does indeed need to change some internal data in `Foo`).